# Add title and subtitle in center of shinydashboard header

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I have the `shinydashboard` below and I would like to add red text like title and subtitle at the center of the `header` like in the image below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(titleWidth = 0,
                  # Set height of dashboardHeader
                  tags$li(class = "dropdown",
                          tags$style(".main-header {max-height: 150px}"),
                          tags$style(".main-header .logo {height: 150px}")
                  )),
  
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('
                            
                            
                            
                            /* body */
                            .content-wrapper, .right-side {
                            background-color: white;
                            }
                            /* navbar (rest of the header) */
    .skin-blue .main-header .navbar {
                          background-color: white;
                          }   
                            ')))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]